# Heroku cannot start jekyll server mode

Tags: heroku, web-deployment, jekyll

Git was deployed data to Heroku. I restart heroku and found log error as below.

> $heroku restart
>
> 2013-01-25T08:17:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to
>   starting 2013-01-25T08:17:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process
>   with command `jekyll --server 27519` 2013-01-25T08:17:30+00:00
>   app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
>   2013-01-25T08:17:32+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status
>   127 2013-01-25T08:17:32+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 2013-01-25T08:28:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from crashed to starting

Suggest improved jkyell file by @jordelver. Open file jkyell at project_jkyell/bin/ changed version number on line from

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Comment: Can you show your Procfile? It looks like the ruby binary cannot be found.

Comment: `web:  jekyll --server $PORT` Command line on Procfile at localhost.

Comment: Have you altered the shebang line (https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/bin/jekyll#L1) in Jekyll? What Heroku stack are you on?